# Display quality issue

Tags: display, desktop-computer

Its seems my display quality worsen, it mostly noticeable in fonts where in some parts of my screen the fonts seems blurry, more thin or more bold. I also notice on very small images and videos, they become little bit like pixelated.

Print screen won't work, I need take a picture from a phone. Take a look at this

[pic1](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtKeZT3HT5esg_BsJlvpo_pXJoEDrw?e=9t5lrx)

[pic2](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtKeZT3HT5esg_BrT_lH0opDXzMYFQ?e=nzVS0L)

Look the menus of notepad at "pic1" and "pic2", you can see the space between the underline and "F" on the "File" menu on "pic1" while "pic2" you can't see the space because it seem it become more bold.

You can also look on this [video](https://1drv.ms/v/s!AtKeZT3HT5esg_BtH5gEFiXRrv3sig?e=qcfBKm) at 00:15 - 00:17, to see the changes.

I also notice a lines or grids-like something on my screen, mostly noticeable on white background and it similar when a monitor screen is being view in a video. Also, in some cases it feels the quality of fonts got better when the monitor is being viewed in a video.

I currently have no idea what cause this, but I notice it first when I playing gta 5. I tried to reinstall the gpu driver but it doesn't fix the issue and also doubting that the driver or windows 10 is causing this because I test this on ubuntu(my system is dual boot) and the issue also exist there.

My pc specs:

CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6-Core Processor 3.60 GHz

GPU: GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER GAMING X

MOBO: MSI B450 TOMAHAWK MAX

RAM: 16 GG G.skill trident z neo (F4-3200C16D-16GTZN) x 2

PSU: Seasonic FOCUS Plus 650 Gold - 650W 80+ Gold ATX12V

MONITOR: ASUS VG258QR Gaming Monitor - 24.5”, Full HD, 0.5ms*, 165Hz, G-SYNC Compatible, Adaptive Sync

Graphic Driver: Geforce Game Ready Drive version 528.02

OS:

- Windows 10 Pro 21H2 19044.2486
- Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: you mention two operating systems, so it's likely a hardware issue with the monitor itself

Comment: @JaromandaX I also think that my monitor is the suspect but the problem is I don't have another monitor that have display port to test this

Comment: In the second picture, the font is not cleanly aligned to the display’s pixels. Try resetting your monitor’s settings to factory defaults.

Comment: @DanielB how do I do that?

Comment: Somewhere in the on-screen menu. Also, try a different DisplayPort cable, different resolutions/refresh rates and fully power cycling all devices (disconnect, then reconnect power entirely).

Comment: How is the monitor connected, what type of cable? Are you 100% certain your computer is set to native resolution? Have you checked that overscan or underscan are disabled in the nVidia control panel?

Comment: @Mokubai my monitor is connected through display port and yes my computer display is set to native resolution. I'm not familiar to overscan or underscan but I will research it